# Repeater inside loginview is null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a loginview with multiple rolegroups and i can't get the repeater reference in codebehind. I'm using the FindControl and write the exact ID of the repeater on it but it's always null... I need to show a different table for each role so I thought loginview was a good choice for this rather than spamming visible true false on codebehind

```
 private void BindListaArtigos()
    {
        try
        {
            int userID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                Repeater rptListaArtigosAdmin = (Repeater)LoginViewRoles.FindControl("rptListaArtigosAdmin");
                rptListaArtigosAdmin.DataSource = Requisicao.GetRequisicoes(userID, "Admin");
                rptListaArtigosAdmin.DataBind();
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Logistica"))
            {
                Repeater rptListaArtigosLogistica = (Repeater)LoginViewRoles.FindControl("rptListaArtigosAdmin");
                rptListaArtigosLogistica.DataSource = Requisicao.GetRequisicoes(userID, "Logistica");
                rptListaArtigosLogistica.DataBind();
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("User"))
            {
                Repeater rptListaArtigosUser = (Repeater)LoginViewRoles.FindControl("rptListaArtigosUser");
                rptListaArtigosUser.DataSource = Requisicao.GetRequisicoes(userID, "User");
                rptListaArtigosUser.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Falha na ligação à base de dados. Tente Novamente mais tarde.');</script>");
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);            
        }
    }
```

Here is the page with loginview

```
 <asp:LoginView ID="LoginViewRoles" runat="server">
                <RoleGroups>
                    <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Dev">
                        <ContentTemplate>

                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptListaArtigosAdmin" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptListaArtigosAdmin_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptListaArtigosAdmin_ItemCommand">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table id="tblAdmin" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>

                                                <th>ID</th>
                                                <th>Nome</th>
                                                <th>Ref. Interna</th>
                                                <th>Validado Logistica</th>
                                                <th>Estado</th>
                                                <th>Data Criação</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="lblIdReq" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdArtigo") %>' />
                                            <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="lblIdUser" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdUser") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:LinkButton Font-Bold="true" runat="server" ID="lkbtnDetalhes" Text='<%# Eval("Nome") %>' CommandName="Ver" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IdArtigo") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" runat="server" ID="lblRefInterna" Text='<%# Eval("ReferenciaInterna") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="lblInfoLog" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AprovadoLogistica") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="lblEstado" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EstadoArtigo") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="lblDataCriacao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DataCriacao") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lknCopiar" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Copiar" CommandName="Copiar" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IdArtigo") %>' Visible="false" />
                                        </td>                              
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lknEditar" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Editar" CommandName="Editar" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IdArtigo") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </table>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>

                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:RoleGroup>
                    <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Logistica">
                        <ContentTemplate>


                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:RoleGroup>
                    <asp:RoleGroup Roles="User">
                        <ContentTemplate>




                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:RoleGroup>
                </RoleGroups>
            </asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: Can you share your ASPX page? Specifically the repeater and the `LoginViewRoles` control.

Comment: it is in the bottom of the code